# Filter table to leave out specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, having

I have the table

```
| WorkerID | ProjectName |  Role  |
|----------|-------------|--------|
|     1    |    Test     | Leader |
|----------|-------------|--------|
|     4    |    Test     | Worker |
|----------|-------------|--------|
|     2    |    Stuff    | Leader |
|----------|-------------|--------|
|     3    |    Proj     | Worker |
```

and now I want to list every ProjectName where there is no specified Leader like this:

```
| ProjectName |
|-------------|
|    Proj     |
```

Right now I only know how to filter all ProjectNames *with* Leaders, but not the way to filter them the other way!

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL! @Zakaria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is with aggregation and the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT ProjectName
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ProjectName
HAVING SUM(Role = 'Leader') = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

(FYI: I'm mostly acquainted with PostgreSQL, so I'm not sure if this is completely transferrable)

I would do a **subquery** to identify the projects that have leaders, and in your main query, do a `WHERE` statement that selects all of the projects that are `NOT IN` the subquery.

```
SELECT ProjectName
FROM Table
WHERE ProjectName NOT IN (
  SELECT ProjectName
  FROM Table
  WHERE Role = 'Leader'
  )
```